# Group Summary Involving dividing in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Crystal Report with about 9 different groups and wanted to be able to have a summary that involves dividing one value by the other.

For example (table):

```
Period    Company   Division   Region  State   City   Store   Employee   Sales   Goal
01-2012   Ab Works  Northern   NW      OR      Ball   888     Foo        100     150
01-2012   Ab Works  Northern   NW      OR      Ball   888     Choo       175     120
02-2012   Ab Works  Southern   SE      GA      Chip   743     Bar        34      75
02-2012   Perrywee  Northern   NC      MN      Fedd   147     Bill       80      64
03-2012   Perrywee  Eastern    FE      WV      Wood   98      Tim        75      250
01-2012   Perrywee  Eastern    FE      WV      Wood   92      Karl       84      250
01-2012   Perrywee  Western    W       CA      Fub    398     Fubar      175     170
```

My output then looks like this:

```
Company   Jan2012   Feb2012   Mar2012 ...  YTD-Avg
Ab Works  70.3%     87.3%     87.5%        84.3%
Perrywee  93.5%     97.3%     130.3%       90.4%
```

Each will allow drilling down to the group below it and the value is calculated by the sum of sales for the group divided by the sum of goals for the group.  As there are 14 periods and 8 groups I want to avoid having to create ~115 formuals.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: You may have to use cross tab reports for achieving this

Comment: A cross-tab will generate the grid that he wants, but cross-tabs don't have a 'drill down' feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar but not using Percentages.  The way I thought it out is almost painful to do, but you will have drilldown capabilities.  I'll post what I've come up with but if someone can modify this to make it easier, by all means.

First, create the 8 groups you want use and hide them.  You will need 14 formulas to create columns for your periods.  For your first period, the formula (and following periods) should look like this:

```
IF {table.period} = "01-2012" THEN
    IF DrillDownGroupLevel = 0 THEN
        SUM({table.sales}, {table.group1}) / SUM({table.goal}, {table.group1})
    ELSE IF DrillDownGroupLevel = 1 THEN
        SUM({table.sales}, {table.group2}) / SUM({table.goal}, {table.group2})
    ELSE IF DrillDownGroupLevel = 2 THEN
        SUM({table.sales}, {table.group3}) / SUM({table.goal}, {table.group3})
    ELSE IF DrillDownGroupLevel = 3 THEN
        SUM({table.sales}, {table.group4}) / SUM({table.goal}, {table.group4})
    ...
    ELSE
        SUM({table.sales}, {table.group8}) / SUM({table.goal}, {table.group8})
ELSE
    0
```

What this formula does is identify what period it is, then determine what group level it is on.  It then Sums up the Sales and Goal considering what the group is suppose to be on that level.

- For line *IF {table.period} = "01-2012" THEN*, I'd set up as a parameter so it will work for multiple years.
- I would rather use a function to determine what group level I was on, but all I know is DrillDownGroupLevel.  It is useful but flawed if you try to do something fancy with the groups (conditional surpression) don't do a simple drilldown.
- Change *{table.group1}* to what ever field you used for that group level. i.e. {table.company}

A drawback on this formula is every time you drill down, the DrillDownGroupLevel will change.  The new level you reveal will be correct, but previous levels that still show will change.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While it doesn't exactly solve my issue it put me on a different path and helped me to get closer to what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

- insert a cross-tab; `company` for row totals; `period` for column totals (set group options to 'for each month'); add `sales` and `goal` to summarized fields
- preview report
- right click a `goal` cell, select 'Embedded Summary', then 'Insert Embedded Summary'
- switch to design mode (cross-tab expert); ensure order (top to bottom) of fields are `@Embedded Summary`, `Sum of Sales`, `Sum of Goal`
- go to preview mode; right click Embedded Summary field and choose 'Edit Calculation Formula'; add the following:

  local numbervar n:=GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex, 1);
  local numbervar d:=GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex, 2);

  if d<>0 then n/d*100
- suppress the sales and goal fields

I haven't (yet) found a way to remove the extra space, however.

Sample:

[image]